# Mule ESB Database Bulk and Batch Process

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

Hi am trying to fetch records from one table and insert into another table (MS SQL) When am fetching its coming as Key Value and am using a batch process to commit with a size of 1000 but when 2000 records comes only two rows where inserted in the table.
I tried using bulk mode but bulk mode is asking for a dynamic query
Below is my query
`INSERT INTO Sample VALUES( #[payload.Index], #[payload.Name])` and the payload is 
`{Index=1,Name=XX},{Index=2,Name=XX},{Index=3,Name=XX}` etc
Please help me how to use bulk mode in Mule ESB and what dynamic query i can write for this.Batch is just posting the first row so I think using bulk inside batch will solve my problem.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mule `bulk mode = "true"` with `parameterized query`.

```
<db:insert config-ref="Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query>
                <![CDATA[INSERT INTO Sample(column1, column2) VALUES( #[payload.Index], #[payload.Name])
            ]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:insert>
```

Check out this [bulk mode link from mule](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/database-connector#bulk-updates)

> Enable to submit collections of data with one query, as opposed to executing one query for every parameter set in a collection. Enabling
>   bulk mode improves the performance of your applications as it reduces
>   the number of individual query executions. Bulk mode requires a
>   parameterized query with at least one parameter.

Just make sure your `payload` is of `Collection` type going into `bulk mode`

In your `log4j2.xml`, add logging for database module in `debug` mode to see actual query passed by mule to database. Great for debugging.

```
 <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.db" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Note that `bulk mode` will **not** work with `batch-processing`. Either of 2 would work though but if your intent is to just insert data, `bulk-mode` is far more efficient than batch.

Comment: Charu thanks for your quick reply.But in error message what I got was cannot use parameterized query when using bulk mode.

Comment: Paste your config and error message, I've code running using `bulk-mode` with `parameterized query`. What's version of Mule are you using?

Comment: Hi charu run time is 3.7.1 and studio 5.4.0

Comment: Bulk mode is working fine but when I use it inside batch its throwing the error. Batch process is not working for MS SQL if i put DB inside batch commit. Its not putting any data inside DB

Comment: Please pay attention to my entire note mentioning "Note that bulk mode will not work with batch-processing. Either of 2 would work though but if your intent is to just insert data, bulk-mode is far more efficient than batch."

Comment: Charu My need is to use bulk inside batch.Anyways thanks its working now.Batch is working with bulk.